After upgrading to 24.10, fortisslvpn stopped working with NetworkManager. Still works in shell
After upgrading to 24.10, 'fortisslvpn' stopped working with NetworkManager.
Launching the openfortivpn connection from the command line works.
Seems related to this bug https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/NetworkManager-fortisslvpn/-/issues/63
Does anyone have a workaround ?

Me too, as far as I know it seems that pppd does not have the required permission. In fact journalctl says "pppd[6592]: Can't execute /etc/ppp/ip-up: Permission denied
" when i try to open the VPN from networkmanager
